# Segmentation fault using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

My Python code crashes with the following error:

```
 Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
```

I use `multiprocessing` to paralellize a function that I later minimize using `scipy.optimize.leastq` My code is as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def myfunction(argss):
   x, data1, data2 = argss
   # evaluating the function at x with data1, data2  as arguments 

def para_function(x, data1, data2, Npr)
    step = int(Ndata/Npr)                                                                                                                                                                                                
    argss = [(x, data1[i*step:(i+1)*step], data2[i*pas:(i+1)*step]) for i in range(Npr-1)]
    argss.append((x, data1[(Npr-1)*step:], data2[(Npr-1)*step:]))
    pool = mp.Pool(Npr)                                                                  
    results = pool.map(myfunction, argss)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # traiting results and returning the function value
```

Then I minimize `para_function()` with `leastsq`. The problem is that I get the error only at the third iteration of minimization! Which means that the first two calls of `para_function` go well and I only get the crash at the third call. I also found out that the error occurs just before the `mp.Pool()` (at the third call of `para_function()` of course), and only with high number of process (`Npr=40`).

Then the program is:

```
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

x0 = np.zeros(N) #The initial guess with N is number of optimization parameters
x = leastsq(para_function, x0, args=(Data1, Data2))
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a minimal example program which does crash?  As an aside, you should not call `multiprocessing` `mpi`.  MPI is a very different thing, and sort of a competitor to multiprocessing.

Comment: I just provided an example in the original post. For the mpi abreviation I know it should be rather used with mpi4py, but it's just a bad habite that I need to change.